# Sum Column values based on datenum in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date, group-by

I am wondering if there is an efficient way of `grouping/summing` `column` values of a `matrix` based on a `serial number date` `column` (in years) in `Matlab version 2013`. To illustrate my point, assuming the data looks like:

```
  737421           3
  737106          -1
  737222           4
  736084           7
  726105          -2
  726442           4
```

`
One is expecting to get:

`6
 7
 2`

*PS:Using the `aggregate` function may solve this issue in a recent version of `Matlab`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my approach:

```
x = [737421  3
     737106 -1
     737222  4
     736084  7
     726105 -2
     726442  4]; % data
[~, ~, u] = unique(datestr(x(:,1), 'yyyy'), 'rows', 'stable'); % convert to years as
     % a 2D char array, and then get unique labels of each year (row) preseving order
y = accumarray(u, x(:,2)); % compute sums grouped by those labels
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just index the date and sum the values, which would be straight forward. The problem would be the size of the array to search. If it is very large you can make a tree out of the data for the `date` would be the Node and you can put the idx into the array as the value at that node. Then search the tree for the starting date and ending date, which will give the you index range in the array to sum. Building the tree and searching is easy and there are examples online.

```
x = [737421  3
     737106 -1
     737222  4
     736084  7
     726105 -2
     726442  4]; % data
idx = x(:,1) >= 737421 & x(:,1) <= 737222;
out = sum(x(idx,2));
```

edit:

```
% Just updating to give one of the values to be correct. 
% There would have to be a for loop to check every 
% year range so @Luis Mendo is the best solution.
idx = x(:,1) >= 737106 & x(:,1) <= 737421; % index for each year
out = sum(x(idx,2));
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. `&&` gives an error, and even if you replace it by `&` the result is `0`

Comment: Yes, I indexed x incorrectly. I didn't have Matlab on my other computer. I'll just edit the response but it looks like you solved his problem.

Comment: Let me know if you correct your answer so that I can remove my downvote

Comment: I updated the `out = sum(x(idx,1))` and the logical `&`

Comment: Haha, I also had to update the `x(idx,1)` to `x(idx,2)`.

Comment: I removed the downvote because now there is no error. However, the result is still `0`